# Misunderstanding or bug? Problem with mapped types

Tags: typescript

Could anybody with a better understanding of TypeScript's type system explain to me why the following does not work?

```js
export const mySchema = {
  user: {
    email: {type: 'string'},
    name: {type: 'string'},
    age: {type: 'number'},
  },
  message: {
    user_id: {type: 'string'},
    text: {type: 'string'},
  },
} as const;

type TypeMap = {
  string: string;
  number: number;
};

// Causes an error
type Instance<TableName extends keyof typeof mySchema> = {
  [Column in keyof typeof mySchema[TableName]]: TypeMap[typeof mySchema[TableName][Column]['type']]; 
};

// Totally fine
type UserInstance = {
  [Column in keyof typeof mySchema['user']]: TypeMap[typeof mySchema['user'][Column]['type']];
};
```

For context I've been trying to create generic instance types for a `const` object that represents a database schema.

In TypeScript 3.8.3, I see the following error:

```
Error:(19, 57) TS2536: Type '"type"' cannot be used to index type '{ readonly user: { readonly email: { readonly type: "string"; }; readonly name: { readonly type: "string"; }; readonly age: { readonly type: "number"; }; }; readonly message: { readonly user_id: { readonly type: "string"; }; readonly text: { ...; }; }; }[TableName][Column]'.
```

Why can't `type` be used to index here, even though `type` always exists?

Despite this, why is everything fine if I hard code `TableName` instead?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer, as my idea at a fix ran into a similar problem to the one you had, but I think the workarounds I provide might prove useful if yours is a real problem.

In order to find an answer to your question, I started from the most general type `TableName` can take. That is `keyof typeof mySchema`. If we investigate `typeof mySchema[TableName]`, we find it's a non-discriminated union, so `keyof` this type is `never`.

From here I branched into two trains of thought.

### 1. Conditional type

You can add a conditional type, to only take the type when it exists.

```js
type InstanceConditionalUnion<TableName extends keyof typeof mySchema> = {
    [Column in keyof typeof mySchema[TableName]]:
        typeof mySchema[TableName][Column] extends {type: any} ?
        TypeMap[typeof mySchema[TableName][Column]['type']] : never; 
};
```

Then `InstanceConditionalUnion<'user'>` is equivalent to `UserInstance`, but `InstanceConditionalUnion<keyof typeof mySchema>` is `{}`.

### 2. Intersection type

To use something like `Instance<keyof typeof mySchema>` we can convert the union to an intersection like this:

```js
type InstanceConditionalIntersection<TableName extends keyof typeof mySchema> = {
    [Column in keyof UnionToIntersection<typeof mySchema[TableName]>]:
        UnionToIntersection<typeof mySchema[TableName]>[Column] extends {type: any} ?
        TypeMap[UnionToIntersection<typeof mySchema[TableName]>[Column]['type']] : never;
};

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
```

With UnionToIntersection taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/4377932).

In this case `InstanceConditionalIntersection<keyof typeof mySchema>` contains all keys from both `user` and `message`

Alas this kind of brings me to a point where my answer doesn't work because `InstanceIntersection` runs into the same problem as your original type.

```js
type InstanceIntersection<TableName extends keyof typeof mySchema> = {
    [Column in keyof UnionToIntersection<typeof mySchema[TableName]>]:
        TypeMap[UnionToIntersection<typeof mySchema[TableName]>[Column]['type']];
}; 
// this is an error. UnionToIntersection<typeof mySchema[TableName]>[Column]
// doesn't have a 'type' property.
```